# Misleading error about incompatible Biblatex/Biber versions

Tags: biber, tectonic

I'm trying to compile a bare bones LaTeX file containing a citation. Using `tectonic`. I get: "Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.8, expected version 3.10.
This means that your biber (2.19) and biblatex (3.17) versions are incompatible." However, upon verification, biblatex/biber are compatible based on CTAN's compatibility matrix. I get no such error with `pdflatex`. What steps can I take to sort out the discrepancy? (my installation is up to date)

debug-8.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bibencoding=auto, backend=biber, sorting=ynt]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{article1,
  author    = {Author One},
  title     = {Title of the Article},
  journal   = {Journal Name},
  year      = {2022},
  pages     = {1-10},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{article1}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

shell 1:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 6.7.3-arch1-1 (linux@archlinux) (gcc (GCC) 13.2.1 20230801, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.42.0) #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu, 01 Feb 2024 10:30:35 +0000
```

shell 2:

```
$ tectonic --version
Tectonic 0.14.1

$ tectonic --keep-logs debug-8.tex
Running TeX ...
Running external tool biber ...
error: the external tool exited with an error code; its stdout was:

===============================================================================
INFO - This is Biber 2.19
INFO - Logfile is 'debug-8.blg'
INFO - Reading 'debug-8.bcf'
ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.8, expected version 3.10.
This means that your biber (2.19) and biblatex (3.17) versions are incompatible.
See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.
INFO - ERRORS: 1
===============================================================================
error: its stderr was:

===============================================================================
===============================================================================
Writing `debug-8.log` (11.06 KiB)
error: the external tool exited with error code 2

$ cat debug-8.log
**
(debug-8.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24> (article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count181
\c@section=\count182
\c@subsection=\count183
\c@subsubsection=\count184
\c@paragraph=\count185

\c@subparagraph=\count186
\c@figure=\count187
\c@table=\count188
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) (biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex 2022/02/02 v3.17 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)
 (pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
 (infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) (iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
(ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode not found.
) (etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count189
) (keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
) (kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
 (kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
))
(logreq.sty
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count190
 (logreq.def
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
)) (ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
) (url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count191
\c@listtotal=\count192
\c@listcount=\count193
\c@liststart=\count194
\c@liststop=\count195
\c@citecount=\count196
\c@citetotal=\count197
\c@multicitecount=\count198
\c@multicitetotal=\count199
\c@instcount=\count266
\c@maxnames=\count267
\c@minnames=\count268
\c@maxitems=\count269
\c@minitems=\count270
\c@citecounter=\count271
\c@maxcitecounter=\count272
\c@savedcitecounter=\count273
\c@uniquelist=\count274
\c@uniquename=\count275
\c@refsection=\count276
\c@refsegment=\count277
\c@maxextratitle=\count278
\c@maxextratitleyear=\count279
\c@maxextraname=\count280
\c@maxextradate=\count281
\c@maxextraalpha=\count282
\c@abbrvpenalty=\count283
\c@highnamepenalty=\count284
\c@lownamepenalty=\count285
\c@maxparens=\count286
\c@parenlevel=\count287
\blx@tempcnta=\count288
\blx@tempcntb=\count289
\blx@tempcntc=\count290
\c@blx@maxsection=\count291
\c@blx@maxsegment@0=\count292
\blx@notetype=\count293
\blx@parenlevel@text=\count294
\blx@parenlevel@foot=\count295
\c@blx@sectionciteorder@0=\count296
\blx@entrysetcounter=\count297
\blx@biblioinstance=\count298
\labelnumberwidth=\skip49
\labelalphawidth=\skip50
\biblabelsep=\skip51
\bibitemsep=\skip52
\bibnamesep=\skip53
\bibinitsep=\skip54
\bibparsep=\skip55
\bibhang=\skip56
\blx@bcfin=\read2
\blx@bcfout=\write3
\blx@langwohyphens=\language87
\c@mincomprange=\count299
\c@maxcomprange=\count300
\c@mincompwidth=\count301
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.
 (blx-dm.def
File: blx-dm.def 2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count302
\c@savedafterword=\count303
\c@annotator=\count304
\c@savedannotator=\count305
\c@author=\count306
\c@savedauthor=\count307
\c@bookauthor=\count308
\c@savedbookauthor=\count309
\c@commentator=\count310
\c@savedcommentator=\count311
\c@editor=\count312
\c@savededitor=\count313
\c@editora=\count314
\c@savededitora=\count315
\c@editorb=\count316
\c@savededitorb=\count317
\c@editorc=\count318
\c@savededitorc=\count319
\c@foreword=\count320
\c@savedforeword=\count321
\c@holder=\count322
\c@savedholder=\count323
\c@introduction=\count324
\c@savedintroduction=\count325
\c@namea=\count326
\c@savednamea=\count327
\c@nameb=\count328
\c@savednameb=\count329
\c@namec=\count330
\c@savednamec=\count331
\c@translator=\count332
\c@savedtranslator=\count333
\c@shortauthor=\count334
\c@savedshortauthor=\count335
\c@shorteditor=\count336
\c@savedshorteditor=\count337
\c@labelname=\count338
\c@savedlabelname=\count339
\c@institution=\count340
\c@savedinstitution=\count341
\c@lista=\count342
\c@savedlista=\count343
\c@listb=\count344
\c@savedlistb=\count345
\c@listc=\count346
\c@savedlistc=\count347
\c@listd=\count348
\c@savedlistd=\count349
\c@liste=\count350
\c@savedliste=\count351
\c@listf=\count352
\c@savedlistf=\count353
\c@location=\count354
\c@savedlocation=\count355
\c@organization=\count356
\c@savedorganization=\count357
\c@origlocation=\count358
\c@savedoriglocation=\count359
\c@origpublisher=\count360
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count361
\c@publisher=\count362
\c@savedpublisher=\count363
\c@language=\count364
\c@savedlanguage=\count365
\c@origlanguage=\count366
\c@savedoriglanguage=\count367
\c@pageref=\count368
\c@savedpageref=\count369
\shorthandwidth=\skip57
\shortjournalwidth=\skip58
\shortserieswidth=\skip59
\shorttitlewidth=\skip60
\shortauthorwidth=\skip61
\shorteditorwidth=\skip62
\locallabelnumberwidth=\skip63
\locallabelalphawidth=\skip64
\localshorthandwidth=\skip65
\localshortjournalwidth=\skip66
\localshortserieswidth=\skip67
\localshorttitlewidth=\skip68
\localshortauthorwidth=\skip69
\localshorteditorwidth=\skip70
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load enhanced support for Unicode engines...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-unicode.def' found.
 (blx-unicode.def)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.
(blx-compat.def
File: blx-compat.def 2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.
 (biblatex.def
File: biblatex.def 2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
\c@textcitecount=\count370
\c@textcitetotal=\count371
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count372
\c@biburlbigbreakpenalty=\count373
\c@biburlbreakpenalty=\count374
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count375
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count376
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count377
\biburlbigskip=\muskip17
\biburlnumskip=\muskip18
\biburlucskip=\muskip19
\biburllcskip=\muskip20
\c@smartand=\count378
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.bbx' found.
 (numeric.bbx
File: numeric.bbx 2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.
 (standard.bbx
File: standard.bbx 2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count379
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count380
))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.cbx' found.
 (numeric.cbx
File: numeric.cbx 2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex citation style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\supercite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcites'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.

(biblatex.cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
)
Package biblatex Info: XeTeX detected.
(biblatex)             Assuming input encoding 'utf8'.
Package biblatex Info: Document encoding is UTF8 ....
 (expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2022-02-24 L3 programming layer (loader) 
 (l3backend-xetex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2022-02-07 L3 backend support: XeTeX
\c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int=\count381
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count382
\g__color_backend_stack_int=\count383
\g__graphics_track_int=\count384
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count385
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count386
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count387
))
Package biblatex Info: ... and expl3
(biblatex)             2022-02-24 L3 programming layer (loader) 
(biblatex)             is new enough (at least 2020/04/06),
(biblatex)             setting 'casechanger=expl3'.
 (blx-case-expl3.sty
(xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2022-01-12 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: blx-case-expl3 2022/02/02 v3.17 expl3 case changing code for biblatex
))

LaTeX Info: Writing file `./debug-8.bib'.

\openout15 = `debug-8.bib'.


\@quotelevel=\count388
\@quotereset=\count389
No file debug-8.aux.
\openout1 = `debug-8.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 1
6.
(ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.
 (english.lbx
File: english.lbx 2022/02/02 v3.17 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: XeTeX detected.
(biblatex)             Assuming input encoding 'utf8'.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'utf8'.
\openout3 = `debug-8.bcf'.

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'debug-8.bbl' not found.

No file debug-8.bbl.
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 16.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 16.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'article1' on page 1 undefined on input line 17.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 18.

[1

] (debug-8.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                debug-8
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'debug-8.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `debug-8.run.xml'.

 )
Output written on debug-8.xdv (1 page, 492 bytes).
```

shell 3:

```
$ find / -name "biblatex" 2>/dev/null
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex
/usr/share/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/biblatex
/usr/share/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex
/usr/share/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/biblatex-ms/biblatex
/usr/share/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/biblatex
/usr/share/doc/texlive/latex/biblatex
/usr/share/doc/texlive/support/cluttex/example/biblatex

$ find / -name 'biblatex.sty' 2>/dev/null
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty


$ cat /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty | grep '\\def\\abx@version'
\def\abx@version{3.19}

$ biber --version
biber version: 2.19
```

shell 4:

```
$ pdflatex debug-8.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./debug-8.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)))

LaTeX Info: File `debug-8.bib' already exists on the system.
            Not generating it from this source.

(./debug-8.aux) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
(./debug-8.bbl) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./debug-8.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please rerun LaTeX.

 )</usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/
texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/font
s/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on debug-8.pdf (1 page, 35504 bytes).
Transcript written on debug-8.log.
[erwann@elitebook tex]$ pdflatex debug-8.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./debug-8.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)))

LaTeX Info: File `debug-8.bib' already exists on the system.
            Not generating it from this source.

(./debug-8.aux) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
(./debug-8.bbl) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./debug-8.aux) )</usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.p
fb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/
texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on debug-8.pdf (1 page, 35504 bytes).
Transcript written on debug-8.log.
```

https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/biblio/biber/base/documentation/biber.pdf

```
Biber version Biblatex version
2.19 3.19
2.18 3.18
2.17 3.17
2.16 3.16
2.15 3.15
2.14 3.14
2.13 3.13
2.12 3.12
2.11 3.11
2.10 3.10
2.9 3.9
2.8 3.8
2.7 3.7
2.6 3.5, 3.6
```

UPDATE:

Before attempting to compile the file, whether with `pdflatex` or `tectonic`, I have deleted auxiliary files:

```
$ rm debug-8 !(*.tex)
```

I assumed `tectonic` pulled `*sty` files from the same directories as `pdflatex`, namely `/usr/share/texmf-dist`, hence my mention of "misleading error" considering the version listed within `bilatex.sty` itself (3.19). Could someone shed light on this?

```
$ which tectonic
/usr/bin/tectonic

$ find / -name tectonic 2>/dev/null
/usr/bin/tectonic
/usr/share/licenses/tectonic
```

Comment: your pdflatex is newer than your tectonic make sure you delete the aux and bcx etc files when switching

Comment: your error says biber 2.19 and biblatex 3.17 and according to the matrix that is wrong. Such version mismatches seem to be a recurring problem in tectonic: https://github.com/tectonic-typesetting/tectonic/issues/893

Comment: The log file of the tectonic run clearly shows that the document is compiled with a LaTeX that accesses a `biblatex` v3.17 installed on your machine. Unfortunately, the log file does not mention the file name (which it usually does), so the tectonic setup appears to be slightly unusual. In any case the `biblatex` v3.19 you *also* have on your machine is not picked up by tectonic. As Ulrike says, this is a common issue with tectonic, because their setup is slightly unusual. It's probably best to check over at GitHub if any of the solutions work or open a new ticket.